# Check for the status of insufficient balance from Stripe during create subscription

Tags: php, stripe-payments

Currently I am facing an issue of not able to retrieve the status of insufficient balance during subscription creation. I am using the below link to retrieve status as a reference, but not able to do this.

Any help or guidance will be appreciable.
https://stripe.com/docs/testing#cards-responses

Comment: _"not able to do this"_ What's not working? What error are you getting? What code are you using?

Answer (score 0):

If you [follow the guide](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/elements#create-subscription) using `payment_behavior=default_incomplete` and then confirm the `subscription.latest_invoice.payment_intent` with `confirmCardPayment` to [complete the payment](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/elements#complete-payment) you should be able to use the insufficient balance test card and get this decline message.